# JQuery UI draggable conflicts with Wijmo draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, wijmo

I am using JQuery UI for its drag and drop feature and Wijmo (a javascript UI library) for menu bar. However the 'draggable' function in JQuery UI won't work along with Wijmo library since there is also a 'draggable' function in Wijmo. How can the program tell which function it is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind the "draggable" events together.

```
$('#foo').bind('draggable', function() {
    //code goes here
});
```

Or even...

```
$('#foo').bind({
    draggable: function() {
       // do something on drag
    },
    droppable: function() {
       // do something on drop
    }
});
```

Comment: I got it working now... 
It turned out to be the version of JQuery that Wijmo uses...
I was using JQuery 1.8.2 and JQuery UI 1.8.23 from Google's CDN and it didn't work with Wjimo.
Right after I changed to the version that Wijmo asks (JQuery 1.7.1 and JQuery UI 1.8.17) the problem was gone.